# Intrensic atomic functions usage instead of semaphores

Tags: operating-system

Can anybody explain how can a intrensic atomic functions be used as alternative to semaphores?

Recnetly I came across a issue where cpu halted due to canonical order violation of semaphores usage. This issue was fixed by using intrensic atomic functions instead of acquiring semaphore to get a lock on the cpu global memory.

I didnot understand this intrensic atomic functions usage to access the cpu global memory.

Thanks,
Ivak.

Answer (score 0):

In fact also semaphores rely on atomic functions (in most implementations) - look on [spinlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) - these are something like low level semaphores with different performance characeteristics.

However, there are sometimes situation where the critical section holds operation so simple that it can be done atomically - e.g. incrementing a counter. There are more complicated things, like enqueuing an element into a queue, which can be done through atomics (although not just with a single operation).

Anyway, using a semaphore could result in deadlock in some circumstances, using lock-free operations you just don't lock anything, so you can't violate the locking order.

Of course, atomic operations are not everything-capable, some data structures just can't be lock-free, sometimes you do a complicated operation over network during which you have to be locked... Semaphores are still required.

And with buggy code using atomics, even if you don't end up with a thread forever sleeping on the semaphore, you can end up with a thread spinning in a loop.